# BreezeJS compatibility with Entity Framework (EF) 6.1

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, entity-framework-6.1

I have just updated (via NuGet) to EntityFramework version 6.1 and Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6 version 1.4.11.

My repository (which extends Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider) now shows an error when I try to override BeforeSaveEntity saying that there is no suitable method for override.

```
protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo) {
```

My controller then tries to access various breeze functions from the repository and receives errors saying that the symbols can not be resolved.

```
this.Repository.Metadata();
```

and

```
this.Repository.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
```

It seems to me that ContextProvider.EF6 is not compatible with EF6.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.

Ensure that Nuget Package Restore is enabled.

Delete the packages folder.

Restore all the packages (either by building the application or going to the Package Manager and allowing it to restore the packages.

Problem solved :).